# Google colab - google drive interface: reliable refresh

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to used Google Drive and Google Colab to run some online data analysis while a detector is taking data. The detector is connected to a computer, and saves `.txt` files to Google Drive as it takes data. Currently this computer is connected to the internet only over wifi, and therefore the upload speed is definitely not infinite. In future, however, it may be possible to connect the computer via ethernet cable and this might speed up the synchronisation from this end

I then have a separate computer, also connected to wifi, from which I use a google colab `.ipynb` to analyse the files.

I mount Google Drive using the standard:

```
# import the data
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive',force_remount=True)
```

but once I've run the script once to analyse the first few files synchronised to Google Drive, when I run it again, even if new files have synced it doesn't necessarily find them, even with `force_remount=True`. The only reliable solution I've found to the problem is disconnecting the runtime and starting again from the beginning, which is fine but slow and not ideal.

Is there a better way of forcing Google Drive to reread everything? Is the problem really somewhere else?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Edit2: I'm pretty sure the synchronisation time isn't the problem - I had moved all of the files out of the directory I was working with, and although looking at Drive in a separate Chrome tab showed new files from a new data acquisition in that folder, my colab notebook couldn't find them until I disconnected and reconnected the runtime

Comment: Maybe you must upload the files to "session storage" instead of uploading locally to google drive?